# $V$ be a f.d.v.s over a field $K$ . The $K[x]$-module on V admits a basis $\iff $ V={0}

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem:**
Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $K$ and let $T$ be an endomorphism on V. Show that, for the corresponding structure of a $K[x]$-module, $V$ admits a basis if and only if $V = ${$0$}.

***Thoughts:***
This amounts to showing that no generating set of a $K[x]$ module on V can be linearly independent but I am not sure how to proceed. Hints and insights appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $V$ is finitely dimensional say of dimension $n$, for every $v\in V$ the set

$$\{v,Tv,\ldots,T^nv\}$$
is linearly dependent over $k$. This means every singleton $\{v\}$ is $k[X]$-linearly dependent, so $V$ has no $k[X]$-basis as soon as it is nontrivial. We have shown, in fact, that $V$ is a *torsion* $k[X]$-module, and free modules are *torsion-free*.

Comment: Was just thinking this! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is a module over $k[x]$, a  PID. A module  structure on $V$ is determined once we know what $x.v$ is for all $v\in V$. This $x$ action has to be an endomorphism of $V$ as a $k$-vector space; assume $V$ has dimension at least 1 (but finite); fixing a basis of $V$ let us call  that endomorphism one given by a matrix $A$.

One can find $f(x)$ such that $f(x).v$ is the zero vector. That $f(A).v=0$ for all $v\in V$. By Cayley-Hamilton theorem when $f$ is chosen as the characteristic polynomial of $A$, we get $f(A).v\equiv 0$ in $V$

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Cayley-Hamilton, it is in a later chapter of my book, are there any other reasonings? Thanks +1.

Comment: If you have not studied matrices and Cayley  Hamilton, then  studying modules is premature. One can, for argument's sake, say modules can be studied without knowledge of vector spaces. But that would not be advisable.

Comment: You're introducing lots of names but not making it clear that every vector admits a minimal polynomial, and hence $V$ cannot be free as a $k[X]$-module, because every element is torsion.

Comment: Undergraduates, even those  not majoring is maths, have heard about Cayley-Hamilton.  Minimal polynomial, IMO, is a subtler concept than characteristic polynomial.  Most learners can write down the characteristic polynomial of a matrix easier than the minimal polynomial.